# Problem booting Ubuntu 12.04 after hibernate/suspend

Tags: boot, suspend

> Linux 3.2.0-38-generic #61-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 19 12:18:21 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
> Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
> Release:        12.04
> Codename:       precise

Before doing `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` I was able to successfully suspend the machine by using `/etc/acpi/sleep.sh`.

After that now when the machine boots it hangs and the only way to boot is by choosing `recovery mode -> resume boot`.

I am attaching the output of `dmesg` at the moment of crash:

- [`dmesg`](http://pastebin.com/SxBxNreL)
- [`cat /proc/acpi/wakeup > wakeup`](http://pastebin.com/GtYbfZ6Z)

Comment: If this problem still happens could you add the `/debug/dri/0/i915_error_state` file after the error happens?